# Python Switching Tabs - Linux

Tags: python, selenium, terminal, tabs, chromium

I am currently making some fun little python projects and one of them is a recipe finder on google. I am using a Linux PC and selenium (chromium) to google the ingredients I input through the terminal. The problem I am having is really more aesthetic than anything else, but I have invested enough time into finding a solution that I am now dedicated to fixing my program.

It launches the web interface and then stays open. I need it to switch back to the terminal I used to initiate the program so that I can input my ingredients. I have been using Super + Tab, but I can't for the life of me find a way to make my program enter Super + Tab.

below is the skeleton of the code I have been using to troubleshoot:

```
from selenium import webdriver
web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.get('https://www.google.com')
print('testing')
web.minimize_window
input('did it work?')
```

I have already tried importing keyboard, using keys.key, virtual key codes, and as you can see here minimizing the window, yet I have not been able to figure out what I need to do. The issue is complicated by the fact that I am on Linux.

Any feedback is appreciated, but if you are going to reply with a why do you need it or a you shouldn't do it the way you're doing it, thats stupid (end of reply), then please save us both some time and do something you enjoy (unless its making noobs feel bad, then do something else)

Comment: What do you mean by `Super + Tab` ?

Comment: On windows you can switch programs that are active with ALT + TAB. On Linux you can do this as well but the keyboard shortcut is the super key (command for mac, the windows logo key for windows) and tab.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `headless mode` for this.

In `headless mode` you can execute your selenium script without opening/seeing the UI.

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
web = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
web.get('https://www.google.com')
print('testing')
input('did it work?')
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this solution.

Edit: I tried this and the issue persists. Thank you for the lead however, I may be able to use this on the program to make it more efficient.

Comment: What is the error that you got ?

Comment: desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'